# Django REST Framework - CurrentUserDefault use

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the `CurrentUserDefault` class for one serializer.

```
user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

The docs says:

> In order to use this, the 'request' must have been provided as part of
>   the context dictionary when instantiating the serializer.

I'm not sure how to create the serializer. On the view I create all the serializers with:

```
serializer = NewModelSerializer(data=request.data)
```

So I've attempted:

```
context = dict(request.data)
context['request'] = request
serializer = NewModelSerializer(data=context)
```

and

```
context['request'] = {'user': request.user}
```

And in both cases the error is the same:

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    'request'
on:
/Users/Alfonso/virtualenvs/sports/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py in set_context

        self.user = serializer_field.context['request'].user
```

Also I tried to unicode the keys of the dictionary (`u'request'`) with same luck.

Is there a better way to pass the logged user to a serializer?

I'm using Django REST Framework 3.0 and Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Django REST Framework handles the serialization and deserialization of objects using a central serializer. In order to help deserialize and serialize sometimes, it needs a bit of context like the current `view` or `request` that is being used. You typically don't have to worry about it because the generic views handle it automatically for you. This is covered in the documentation under ["Including extra context"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) and it takes advantage of the optional `context` parameter for serializers.

When you are using serializers manually, the context must be passed in as a dictionary. Some fields require specific keys, but for the most part you only need the `request` key to be a reference to the incoming request. This will allow the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to generate a full URL, and extras like the `CurrentUserDefault` to perform as expected.

```
context = {
    "request": self.request,
}

serializer = NewModelSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
```

The context dictionary is also available on generic views as the `get_serializer_context` method, which will automatically populate the dictionary with commonly used keys such as the `request` and `view`.

Comment: You sir saved my christmas

Comment: This is very helpful. And unfortunately the error it throws if you don't supply the extra context is not very helpful at all. It throws a KeyError exception with the message u'request'.