# CurrentUserDefault doesn't work with AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use [`CurrentUserDefault`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) with a field that can be null:

```py
# model
class Package(models.Model):
    # User can be empty because we allow anonymous donations
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

# serializer
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

Everything works fine when a user is logged in. However, if a user is not authenticated I get this:

```
ValueError at /api/organizations/village/packages/
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7fc97ad6d940>": "Package.owner" must be a "User" instance.
```

**Is there a reason why `CurrentUserDefault` doesn't work with anonymous users?**

P.S. I know I can use this instead of `CurrentUserDefault` and it will work:

```py
class AuthorizedUserOrNone:
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, serializer_field):
        user = serializer_field.context["request"].user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return user

        return None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s()" % self.__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you return if `user.is_anonymous`? Work that out and add that to `def __call__(self, serializer_field)` and you should be good. `CurrentUserDefault` does not appear to handle anonymous users.

Try:
`get_object_or_404(User, fk_user=self.request.user)`

This answer provides more helpful context: [Django REST Framework - CurrentUserDefault use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632385/django-rest-framework-currentuserdefault-use)

Based on what I'm reading in the Traceback, unless you dive deeper into the code base behind the `CurrentUserDefault` class I don't think there is a standard way of handling this. My limited research has shown me that `CurrentUserDefault` doesn't appear to be designed to handle anonymous requests (which fits, given the word "User" in the class). The Traceback seems to align with this.

If I am correct, and you're dealing with an edge-case, then more modifications will likely be required to accomplish what you're looking for. Good luck. Sorry I couldn't help with a direct answer.

Note: the above is untested.

See: [Django REST documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about anonymous user. It only says that `request` must be in serializer context.

Comment: If user is anonymous, I want Package be saved with `owner=None`.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632385/django-rest-framework-currentuserdefault-use

Comment: Thank you for the link @Carewen. I took a look and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The more I look at the ValueError the more it looks like it's built to require a User object. But with the Anonymous context it's getting tripped up. Have you looked at the inherited code base? Can you find where it's handling user objects? There's a good chance of getting clear on why the ValueError is being kicked up by going down that rabbit hole. Good luck!

Comment: What about having the User attribute be nullable, and getting the same outcome? In other words, rather than explicitly save None to the owner attribute just leave it as Null? It's a bypass that should hopefully avoid the problem, and can still be tested for later on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The `owner` field of the `Package` model has `null=True, blank=True`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247959/discussion-between-carewen-and-serhii-holinei).